# Components are accessable via console on production?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, production

I recently deployed a website for a friend of mine, written in React, Express, Mongodb, etc... And I can see that I have a console.log on one of the components and wanted to ask if that's normal that a component is accessible via a console.log? (I can access the source code because of that).

And is there a solution for that or just removing ALL console.log before production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you used `create-react-app` to start the project, it generates sourcemaps when you run the build script by default. You can disable this by adding `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` in your `.env` file.

As for the console logs, you can either change `console.log` to `console.debug` (which only shows in the browser console when you have verbose logging enabled) or you can rely on some linting rule (like [this](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console)) to prevent the use of console altogether.